# What are the tables used for storing the Drupal site-information

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

What are the tables used for storing the site-information like site_name,site_frontpage etc in Drupal6

Answer (score 1):

Drupal modules use the `variable` table to store all kinds of configuration settings. In Drupal 6 the table has two fields, `name` and `value`, which I think are self-explained. You will find the data you mentioned among many other variables. You need to be aware that the `value` field cointains serialized data.

The [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module provides a menu link to list and edit variables.